# Convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-writing

1) Let (x_n) be a sequence and let *L* ∈ R. Suppose that for each `ϵ > 0`,

{k ∈ N : x_k ∈ B(*L*; ϵ)}

is infinite. Show that (x_n) has a subsequence converging to *L*.

2) Suppose that S is not a compact subset of R. Explain why there is a sequence (y_n) in S so that no subsequence of (y_n) converges to any *L* in S.

My idea is to let ϵ = 1, and let a subsequence m ∈ N, such that m_1 < m_2 < m_3 < ... and `x_(m_k) ∈ B( l ; 1/k)` for all k ∈ N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, take $\epsilon = 1/k$, then
   $$
   B_k := \{n \in \mathbb{N} : x_n \in B(l,\epsilon)\}
   $$
   is infinite (and thus non-empty). Now choose the $x_{n_k}$ inductively, so that
   $$
   x_{n_k} \in B_k\setminus\{x_{n_j} : 1\leq j < k\}
   $$
   Then $x_{n_k} \to l$
2. Choose an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $S$ which has no finite subcover. Pick $U_1 \in \mathcal{U}$, and $y_1 \in U_1\cap S$. Having chosen $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_{k-1}$, pick an open set $U_k \in \mathcal{U}$ such that
   $$
   S\cap U_k\setminus \left (\bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} U_j\right ) \neq \emptyset
   $$
   Choose $y_k$ in that set. This inductively builds a sequence $(y_n)$ with no convergent subsequence (why?)

Comment: When you take j, is j an arbitrary number?
Since I take ϵ=1/k, can I do |x_(n_k) - L| < 1/k ?